# Force Chrome printing settings

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Is there any way to force Chrome to always print without headers and margins? Chrome keeps forgetting and it really messes up my cash register program (if the header is there, it tries to print the entire page, which is a lot of white space). If you have any CSS, Chrome settings, even hard-coded editing of Chrome itself: anything that can fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change this via your website, you can try using css media queries to hide or rearrange elements for printing.

```
@media print { 
  /* All your print styles go here */
  margin: 0;
  #header, #footer, #nav {
    display: none !important;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to hide the title that displays on the tab and the margins and so forth. These aren't elements on the page that are the problem. Your solution would be if I have an element called "header" right?

Comment: Setting page margins that way apparently doesn't override Chrome's page margins (which are still defaulting). It looks like I'm going to need a hard-coded change to Chrome to force it to behave.

Comment: I found another answer that said `@page { margin: 0; }` and that worked for me, but since your answer led me there: thank you.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, also kiosk mode doesn't sound like something you can manually enable for your users, so I would say that's a non-answer. There's a reason that question is from SU instead of SO.

Comment: Depends on your situation. Rhyono said it was a cash register program so it could be a system they're setting up themselves. It's an possible answer for someone--that's all you can really ask for. I'll remove it since the link is dead, thanks for letting me know. I don't see why you downvoted the whole answer though considering it was a secondary option and the print media selector works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I wanted to override the print options so that the browser's headers and footers did not display.

Putting `@page {margin: 5mm;}` into my CSS file worked perfectly. In fact if you use `@page {margin: 0}` the Headers and Footers option is not even displayed on the Print Preview (in Chrome, I have not yet tested other browsers.